# Histogram fit and kernal Density plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, signal-processing

I want to plot histogram fit and kernel Density curve in one plot means in I figure ks density curve and histfit in one frame .

Can someone help me how to do that.

I am just presenting an example code what I want to do.

Thanks a lot .

```
  x = rand([1 50])
  figure(1)
  histfit(x)
  hold on 
  [f,xi] = ksdensity(x);
  hold off
  figure
  plot(xi,f);
```

Comment: This is a very common task, did you see the docs? If you want both the graphs to overlap in the same figure, put `hold off` after `plot(xi, f)`, and delete the line `figure` just after `hold off`.

Comment: crazy Gamer thanks a lot for comment . it worked great.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, I've added the same as an answer. Please accept it so it keeps us encouraged to help you further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function calls for plotting are incorrect. Essentially, `hold on` asks MATLAB to plot everything thereafter, overlapping the previous figure. `hold off` disables this and overwrites the previous figure. Hence, run the code like this:

```
x = rand([1 50])
figure(1)
histfit(x)
hold on 
[f,xi] = ksdensity(x);
plot(xi,f);
hold off
```